# Extracting data from disarranged xml file using python

Tags: python, xml

I'm new to python and have a problem extracting data from xml file, which looks very disarranged to me. Data I'm looking for are tickers - like AAPL - see below. Thanks for help.

```
</ss:Row>
<ss:Row>
<ss:Cell ss:StyleID="Left">
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">AAPL</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell ss:StyleID="Left">
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">APPLE INC</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell ss:StyleID="Left">
<ss:Data ss:Type="String">Equity</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell ss:StyleID="Right">
<ss:Data ss:Type="Number">3.73173</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell ss:StyleID="Right">
<ss:Data ss:Type="Number">208.74</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell ss:StyleID="Right">
<ss:Data ss:Type="Number">32551247</ss:Data>
</ss:Cell>
<ss:Cell ss:StyleID="Right">
<ss:Data ss:Type="Number">6794747298.78</ss:Data>
```

Comment: What's the code you are already using in order to try to do what you want?

Comment: What you have in the question looks like a fragment of an XML file exported from Excel. Please provide more context and a [mcve].

Comment: I enclose link to the file - https://www.ishares.com/us/products/239726/ishares-core-sp-500-etf/1521942788811.ajax?fileType=xls&fileName=iShares-Core-SP-500-ETF_fund&dataType=fund

Answer (score 0):

ElementTree might be your best friend here (https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html). It helps to arrange your xml and it easien up exploring it and extracting data from it.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
text = "" # copy xml you want to parse; it looks like XML that you pasted is incorrect (you start from closing tag)
root = ET.fromstring(text)
# then you can explore your tree for example:
for el in root:
    print(el.text) # check what text is collected in this tag
```

More information about exploring tree (e.g. finding elements with certain tag) can be found on the webpage that I gave you link to.

Comment: It gives a parse error - ParseError: syntax error: line 1, column 0

Comment: I tried also root = ET.parse(text), but it gives me another error - ParseError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 1

Comment: The problem is that tags such as '<ss:Row>' are considered incorrect. Additionally your XML contains tags taht are not closed. (</Row> is before <Row>)
Try this code with:
text = """<Row>
<Cell StyleID="Left">
<Data Type="String">AAPL</Data>
</Cell>
</Row>
"""

So you need to fix the XML first.